# How to get the mesh(vertex and index buffers) from the object I obtained from the method `getRenderProxy` in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, autodesk-forge

I want to obtain the mesh from the object I obtain from calling `getRenderProxy` method in node.js. This is my implementation, where I pass an ObjectID from the model tree:

```
function getMeshByDbID(dbID) {
var instanceTree = getInstanceTree();

var meshes = [];
let fragIds = [];
instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(
  dbID,
  function (fragId) {
    fragIds.push(fragId);
    
    
  },
  true
);
console.log(fragIds);
fragIds.forEach(function(fragId){
    var mesh = window.NOP_VIEWER.impl.getRenderProxy(
        window.NOP_VIEWER.model,
        fragId);
    meshes.push(mesh);
    
})

return meshes;
```

}

I get an object, as shown below.
[image: getRenderProxy Output Object]

But whenever I try to extract geometry(by calling mesh.geometry) from this object, I get `undefined`. The structure of geometry object within the above object is as follows:
[image: Geometry Object]
I want to get the mesh, specifically, the `ib` and `vb` arrays in the figure above for performing calculations. Any help is appreciated.

Outputs of console.log of `RenderProxy.geometry.vb` for three different runs, This should not be possible:

[image: Run 1]
[image: Run 2]
[image: Run 3]

Comment: Your approach looks good. You can take a look at this article where Philippe described how to do [Boolean operations in the Forge Viewer](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/boolean-operations-forge-viewer).

Comment: I still keep getting `null`, though

Comment: `enumNodeFragments` methods returns `fragId` every time it founds one and you can have multiple fragments for each `dbId` (especially if you use `recursive = true`). You should create an array an push every `fradId` in the array. Then you can find the associated mesh for each `fragId` of the array.

Comment: Is there a way to find mesh from `objectid` that I obtained from json output of `/modelderivative/designdata` api call? Because I want to work on specific meshes and `fragId` seems to be changing for each api call. However, the `objectid` is constant across all the api calls.

Comment: `dbId` and `objectId` are the same thing. There are also called `nodeId` in some cases.

Comment: The object id you passed might not be the leaf node (or so-called instance node). Try to call `enumNodeFragments( dbId, callback, true )` to get fragment ids recursively, as Alex suggested. Yes, dbId and objectId are the same things.

Comment: But, why are then geometry details like `renderProxy.geometry.vb`are different for each API call for same `fragId` of same `dbId`? Is there a bug in my code, which is present in the question?